# New error nessage "Can't use lokkit options with other options." from firewall-offline-cmd

Tags: firewalld, syntax

A few months ago I wrote a script that helps configuring the firewall in SLES15.
However when I ran the script today, I saw a new confusing error message like this:

```text
+ firewall-offline-cmd --zone=public --remove-service=store1
usage: see firewall-offline-cmd man page
Can't use lokkit options with other options.
```

Unfortunately the erro message is quite confusing:
What is the "lokkit" option in the command?

The manual page isn't actually helpful there:

> Some lokkit options can not be automatically converted for firewalld, they will result in an error or warning message.

*I don't want to **convert** anything*!

- I see there's a "**--delete-service=service**" and a "**[--zone=zone]
  --remove-service-from-zone=service**".
- There's also a "**[--zone=zone] [--policy=policy]
  --add-service=service**" (without "**-to-zone**").

For the non-offline version of the command (i.e.: `firewall-cmd`) the options are:

- "**[--permanent] [--zone=zone] [--permanent] [--policy=policy] --add-service=service [--timeout=timeval]**"
- "**[--permanent] [--zone=zone] [--permanent] [--policy=policy] --remove-service=service**"

So this is highly inconsistent!
As my script checks whether the firewall service is running before taking actions (i.e.: deciding whether to use `firewall-cmd` or `firewall-offline-cmd`), it's quite a mess when the commands (options) are very different between `firewall-cmd` and `firewall-offline-cmd`.

In summary:
At least the error message should be

> Unknown option --remove-service

(followed by the usage message)

See also [Inconsistent command names in firewall-cmd and firewall-offline-cmd](https://github.com/firewalld/firewalld/issues/1048).